# Admin (All posts) stop responding problem

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, performance

I have situation like this: I have site with 500+ posts, 10+ custom taxonomies, one of taxonomy have 20000+ terms. When in admin panel I go to Posts-> All posts wordpress opens the page but stops responding (on Chrome “Version 27.0.1453.94 m” and on IE9) and slows down on Firefox 21.0. 
I have tried disabling all plugins but it didn’t help. So I tried to delete part of code from functions.php in my theme where I create hierarchical custom taxonomy (20000+ terms) and it worked like charm.

peace of functions.php where I create custom taxonomy:

```
            $labels = array(
                'name'                       => _x( 'Apskritys', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
                'singular_name'              => _x( 'Apskritis', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'                     => $labels,
                'hierarchical'               => true,
                'public'                     => true,
                'show_ui'                    => true,
                'show_admin_column'          => false,
                'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
                'show_tagcloud'              => true,
            );

            register_taxonomy( 'county', 'post', $args );
```

I would be very grateful for your advice in this situation!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that every time I post a question here I find solution on myself. Sorry for posting.

So my solution in problem described above is: just change 'show_ui' to false.

```
 'show_ui' => false,
```

It helped me.

Sorry again for posting.

Comment: No worries, it's not uncommon to find solution yourself and you posting it will be helpful for others who might encounter same issue. :)